# Need advice with multiple people working on an Access Database

Tags: database, ms-access

This may seem like an ignorant issue, but I am inexperienced with Access. This is for a school project. I am in a group of 5 people who are all working on a database. We were wondering: what is the most efficient way for multiple people to work on a database without sending the database file to and fro or just putting a copy on a file sharing service? Is there a way we can all log in and modify the same database?

Comment: If you are all on the same local area network then store the database on the file server and you will all be able to open *the same copy* of the database at the same time.  If you are located remotely from each other there is no simple solution without changing from Access to another, client-server, database product.

Comment: Are you all writing to the DB, or creating and modifying Access objects: tables, queries, forms etc.? in any case please read [this post](http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-25.html) on corruption.

Comment: I would also like to hear people's experience about Access DBs in file sharing: DropBox, Google Drive, etc...

Comment: Don't use Access!!! Use MySQL or some other open source DB. Access is designed as a single-user DB and lacks proper multi-user support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for file sharing service, well, [this expert](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28494992/Access-and-Google-Drive.html) [and this one too](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/749765-sharing-access-database-via-online-storage-dropbox-google-drive-etc-can-done.html) say it doesn't work.

Comment: You could either work on a Local Aria Network (LAN), or, I suggest, have one member Manage the DB: all others send data to him, and he updates the DB.

Comment: You could also on a remote desktop, [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) is a great remote desktop service.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this. If you put the database file in a shared location where everyone can access it. You need to change the database locking options so that multiple users can make changes to it.

In Access 2013 go to *File->Client Settings->Advanced* and change the **Open Mode** to shared, also change **Record locking** to **Edited Records** - this will enable uses to make changes but not to the same record.

If you want users to make changes to the same record select **No Locks** but it is not a good idea as if two users change at the same time the last one will be saved.